# How can i split my integer inputs into 2 digits and remaining one digit as one?

Tags: python

My integer input is suppos 2233445, I want to split and put it into an array as 22, 33, 44, 5.And append them to a list. How will I be able to do it?

Comment: What is the logic behind that split?  For example, what if the input were 122333445?

Comment: its simple, that the output should be 2 digits. If the length of the number is odd then the last digit should be placed alone. e.g(12,23,33,44,5)

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the string

```
data="2233445"
split_strings = [] # final list
n = 2 # length of spliting
for index in range(0, len(data), n):
    split_strings.append(data[index : index + n])
print(split_strings)
```

Comment: Can we do the same process if we don't convert or consider the input as string value?

Comment: @MohamedMahir You can use `str(data)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with regex and get result as `list`,

```
import re
result = re.findall('..?','2233445')
print(result)
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/PWV44308

Comment: Can we do the same process if we don't convert or consider the input as string value?

Comment: no, for number you need to do it another way. or cast it to string i.e `str(2233445)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = str(2233445)
output = [int(s[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
```

output

```
>>> [22, 33, 44, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
number = 2233445
number = str(number)
pairs = [int(number[i: i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(number), 2)]
print(pairs)

[22, 33, 44, 5]
```

Comment: The purpose why I asked this question is because I have to print the sum of 2 digits of the input. Like


input = 1122334

output = 66
So that I came up with a logic of splitting the integer into every 2 digits and use a while loop to increment a variable with the 2 digit values. I succeed. If there is any alternative logic to reduce the lines of codes I will be glad.

the loop I used:

Comment: The given answer is for the question you asked.. If not, you have to explictly state your question.

Comment: sorry about that. I really intended to know how to split the integers as I asked.